# I need to send email from my website in PHP. How can I do this?

Tags: php, email, unix, centos, shell-exec

I need to send email from my website in PHP. By requirement, I can not use the built in mail() PHP function (so no sendmail). I downloaded 'mail' on my unix server and through a function in PHP should be able to connect in order to send emails. The PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
    function sendMail() {
        shell_exec("echo mymessage | mail -s mysubject myreal@email.com");
    }
?>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, but if I run that command in the unix terminal (the machine is a Centos 7) it works. I also tried the system() and exec() PHP function, but without success. How can I do this work?
Thanks

EDIT:
This question is not the same. I must not use the mail() PHP function but an alternative

Comment: Try something like PHPMailer?

Comment: Thanks. I used PHPMailer and it works fine. I can't understand why my question is so negative...

Answer (score 0):

Most frameworks have come to the same conclusion that `mail()` is not a good solution to send mail. What most frameworks do nowadays is they [open a socket](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php#L276) and pipe the mail commands directly over said socket. That's why using something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html) (which doesn't require you to use the entire framework) is preferred. It's a cleaner overall solution.

Your web services user may not have permissions to use the built-in Linux client. That's most likely why the shell command doesn't work. I would highly suggest avoiding shell commands and disabling them, as they are security risks.